# SQL Server - getting the correct price for the date period of an activity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some activity occurrences with the date range they occur across:

**ActivityOccurrence:**

- ID: 1, ActivityID: 1, StartDate: 2018-05-01, EndDate: 2018-06-30
- ID: 2, ActivityID: 2, StartDate: 2018-06-01, EndDate: 2018-07-31
- ID: 3, ActivityID: 3, StartDate: 2018-07-01, EndDate: 2018-08-31

Each activity has a price which apply within an effective period:

**EffectivePeriod**

- ID: 1, ActivityID: 1, ValidFrom: 2018-01-01, ValidTo: 2018-06-30, Price: 50
- ID: 2, ActivityID: 2, ValidFrom: 2018-01-01, ValidTo: 2018-06-30, Price: 100
- ID: 3, ActivityID: 3, ValidFrom: 2018-01-01, ValidTo: 2018-06-30, Price: 70
- ID: 4, ActivityID: 1, ValidFrom: 2018-07-01, ValidTo: 2018-12-31, Price: 55
- ID: 5, ActivityID: 2, ValidFrom: 2018-07-01, ValidTo: 2018-12-31, Price: 120
- ID: 6, ActivityID: 3, ValidFrom: 2018-07-01, ValidTo: 2018-12-31, Price: 80

I'd like to link the Activity Occurrences with their correct rates. So:

- ActivityOccurrence ID of 1 would link with EffectivePeriod ID of 1, spanning only the first effective period.
- ActivityOccurrence ID of 2 would link with both EffectivePeriod ID of 2 and 5 as it spans across 2 effective periods.
- ActivityOccurrence ID of 3 would link with EffectivePeriod ID of 6, spanning only the second effective period.

Doing a standard `JOIN` gets both effective periods for all 3 activity occurrences which I don't want. Using `StartDate >= ValidFrom` is correct for the first activity occurrence, but not the second and third. Using `StartDate <= ValidTo` means the first one is wrong, but the second and third are correct. Switching `StartDate` to `EndDate` also has some issues.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/576c6/6

I feel like I'm missing something and the answer is very simple but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to make sure that each ActivityOccurrence is joined with EACH EffectivePeriod that is temporally included in its date range?

What I use in such cases is make sure either start or end date of one table is between the start-end of the other:

```
SELECT ao.ActivityID, ao.StartDate, ao.EndDate, ep.Price
FROM ActivityOccurrence ao
JOIN EffectivePeriod ep ON ao.ActivityID = ep.ActivityID
AND 
(
    (ao.StartDate between ep.ValidFrom and ep.ValidTo)
    OR
    (ao.EndDate between ep.ValidFrom and ep.ValidTo)
)
```